# Building 32b binary on 64b platform

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, ld

The platform in question is Debian.  I have installed: gcc-multilib g++-multilib

However, I keep getting this error when linking:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so when searching for -lcrypt
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.a when searching for -lcrypt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so when searching for -lcrypt
```

I cannot find an answer to this.